# How can I pop the list element from front?

Tags: python

I have a list in bellow:

```
stack = [1,2,3,4,5]
stack.append(6)

print stack

stack.pop()

print stack # there output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I have a requirement is I want pop from front, but it has no the feature seemingly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) says you can specify an index

```
>>> stack = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> stack.pop(0)
1
>>> stack
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to achieve that:

1. You can use the `deque` in python, which has a `popleft()` method:

   ```
   from collections import deque

   deque_list = deque([1,2,3,4,5])
   deque_list.popleft()

   print deque_list
   ```

It will shows `deque([2, 3, 4, 5])` in the output, and its usage is like the list.

2. And you can also use `pop(0)` to pop from front:

   ```
   stack = [1,2,3,4,5]
   stack.pop(0)  # 1
   ```

Answer (score 5):

The pop method accepts an argument, which is the index to pop. The default is -1, which indicates the last element. To pop the firs element, you do:

```
stack.pop(0)
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#mutable-sequence-types).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (`pop(0)`) is the canonical way of doing this, but in the absence of that a simple alternative using readily available builtins is reversing the list such that popping effectively becomes popping from the front:

```
>>> stack = list(reversed([1,2,3,4,5]))
>>> stack.pop()
1
>>> stack.pop()
2
```

or with in-place reversal:

```
>>> stack = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> stack.reverse()
>>> stack.pop()
1
>>> stack.pop()
2
```